# Second order differential equation with Heaviside function

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, distribution-theory

I have a differential equation of the form 
$$y''(x) - a y(x) + b \theta(c - x) = 0, \quad y(0) = 0, \quad \lim_{x \to \infty} y(x) = 0,$$
where $a$, $b$, $c$ are some constants and $\theta(с - x)$ is the Heaviside function.
If there was any condition for the derivative, I would simply use Laplace transform and that's it, but here I seemingly have to search for the solution directly: 
$$y = C_1 e^{\sqrt a x} + C_2 e^{-\sqrt a x} + C_3 f(x)$$
And I've got no idea what function $f(x)$ might be. Please, help me out.

Comment: You can still do Laplace transform, but keep $y'(0)$ as a constant to be determined. Then use the boundary condition at $\infty$ to determine that constant. Also by the way, in your general solution, there shouldn't be a $C_3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, it turns out to be pretty easy. The equation simply says that in $x \in [0, c)$ it has the form $y''(x) - a y(x) +  b = 0$ and in $x > c$: $y''(x) - a y(x) = 0$. Boundary conditions give trivial solution on $x > c$, so I can treat $\theta$-function on $[0, c)$ as a constant to obtain:
$$y(x) = b\theta(c - x)(e^{-\sqrt a x} + 1)$$